# Does the consumer key and secret for a Connect App change on sandbox refresh?

Tags: api, connected-apps

The [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_terminology.htm&type=5) mention the terminology involving the consumer key and secret, but I have not come across anything that effects their original values when you do a sandbox refresh.

Long story short, one of our test servers cannot connected to our sandbox, even though I've verified that they have the correct consumer key, secret, and callback url.

Comment: Was the Connected App created *in* the sandbox?

Comment: did you checked the connected app request is reaching your sandbox ?  it is available under Connected Apps OAuth Usage. If you have mydomain enabled issuer changes as well as if you are using any certificates.

Comment: @sfdcfox it was created in Production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the consumer key and secret are changed when the sandbox is refreshed.

Comment: any idea why you are still able to use the client_id and client_secret that you had before the refreshing?

I've just noticed that this is possible.